# SQL - Remove double semicolons at the end of field

Tags: sql, regex, string, amazon-redshift, character-trimming

We are using Amazon-Redshift (PostgreSQL compliant syntax), we have the following string in a table

```
"TOTO;"
"TOTO;;"
"TOTO;;;"
"TOTO;;;;"
```

I would like to 'rtrim' double semicolons. So I would like to have

```
"TOTO;"
"TOTO"
"TOTO;"
"TOTO"
```

How to do it?

Comment: Have you tried the trim operator? (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-string.html)

Comment: if we do select trim('toto;;;', ';;'), it removes all ';' ...

Comment: This would work - `(?:;;)+` Demo: https://regex101.com/r/cEQbB5/1

Comment: @Gurman: You'll need a `$` at the end to avoid removing every `;;` in the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `regexp_replace` function with the `(;;)*$` regex (any number of `;;` followed by the end of the line):

```
SELECT regexp_replace(';;test;;;', '(;;)*$'), regexp_replace(';;test;;;;', '(;;)*$');
┌────────────────┬────────────────┐
│ regexp_replace │ regexp_replace │
├────────────────┼────────────────┤
│ ;;test;        │ ;;test         │
└────────────────┴────────────────┘
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select replace('TODO;;;',';;','')
```

If I’ve made a bad assumption please comment and I’ll refocus my answer.

Comment: This will remove all `;;` occurences, not just the trailing ones.

Comment: @Marth - My bad! regexp_replace is the solution.